# eclipse plugin add description to table/tabfolder

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I'm building a plugin for eclipse and have the following code to put a tabfolder in my view:

```
private void constructViewWindow(Composite parent){

   final TabFolder tabFolder = new TabFolder(parent, SWT.NONE);

   terminologyTab = new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
   grammarTab = new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
   styleTab = new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);
   xmlTab = new TabItem(tabFolder, SWT.NONE);

   terminologyTable = new Table(tabFolder, SWT.BORDER);
   grammarTable = new Table(tabFolder, SWT.BORDER);
   styleTable = new Table(tabFolder, SWT.BORDER);
   xmlTable = new Table(tabFolder, SWT.BORDER);

   addTableColumns(terminologyTable);
   addTableColumns(grammarTable);
   addTableColumns(styleTable);
   addTableColumns(xmlTable);


   terminologyTab.setControl(terminologyTable);
   grammarTab.setControl(grammarTable);
   styleTab.setControl(styleTable);
   xmlTab.setControl(xmlTable);

   }
```

which results in the following window:

[image]

which is very nice. But I now want to add a description/some additional information to this, something that ends up in the same spot as the '0 items' text in the Tasks view:

[image]

Since I'm not sure what this would be called, googling is a bit difficult (e.g. I've tried "add header to table", but a header is obviously something else. "Description" didn't really do the trick either). I guess one could find this in the eclipse source code somewhere, but as I'm new to Java, and diving in the eclipse sources and finding what I need will take quite some time (at least for me), anyone any ideas on how to add this additional line of text above my TabFolder?

Answer (score 0):

Just add a `Label` to the composite before the tab folder.

```
private void constructViewWindow(Composite parent){

   label = new Label(parent, SWT.LEFT);

   // TODO set layout on the layout

   label.setText("0 items");

   final TabFolder tabFolder = new TabFolder(parent, SWT.NONE);
```

You may need to set Layout Data on the label to make sure it is wide enough for the text.

Another way is to use the `ViewForm` class which lets you put controls at the corners of the page.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I had tried adding a label already, exactly in the way you propose. But that leads to a large blank space with the text I set in it (with .setText) to the left of my table/tabfolder. And it's the same size as the complete tabfolder, whereas I was aiming at just a small text field above my tabfolder (hope you know what I mean, a screenshot would explain perfectly, but I can't seem to post one in a comment (which makes sense in itself, of course..))

Comment: That is a problem with the Layout you are using. Show us the code creating the Composite and setting the Layout

Comment: Ok. Since I really only have limited experience with Java and I started out with an eclipse plugin view tutorial (and expanded upon that), it all started with the `public void createPartControl(Composite parent) ` that was already in the plugin code. To be brutally honest, I was wondering already where this Composite came from, but assumed that it was just something that you get 'for free'/automatically when you create a plugin project in Eclipse. Anyway; guess the code creating the Composite is not really in my control (in any case, I'm too much of a Java beginner to modify/look into that)

Comment: Yes you get that Composite 'for free' but it is using `FillLayout` which gives equal space to each child control. Normally you create a single `Composite` as the only child of this composite and add your controls to that using some other layout such as `GridLayout`.

Comment: Ok. If you don't mind, I'm not going to accept your answer, since my problem remains. But good to know that it is just a shortcoming of the way I implemented my plugin. I'll try to look into re-doing that. Thanks a lot for now!